# ExpressionEngine custom url routing

Tags: php, expressionengine

From what I understand, Expression Engine url parsing works like this:

```
          site/template/
```

I want to deeplink straight off the regular site url, like this:

```
          site/special-deep-link
```

and I have javascript in place to carry out specific actions.

But EE is just assuming this is a template, and giving me a 404 saying it does not exist (which is true).  So naturally the js does not fire and nothing works.

Is there any way to stop EE from trying to parse it as a template without using .htaccess or other server side config settings?

Unfortunately the old codeigniter way of rule routing doesn't seem to be working.

I tried:

```
           $route['site/special-deep-link'] ='';
           $route['/special-deep-link'] ='';
           $route['index/special-deep-link'] ='';
```

But sadly none of those seem to work.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, using this plugin:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie

I was able to have EE ignore that url string.